# How to print notification to slack by calling a function via python

Tags: python, oop

I know how basically to print use slack API to send notification to slack , for example if i have a slack channel named #testbot , so i can print notification as:

```
slack.chat.post_message('#testbot','This is a test',username='NMAP_bot')
```

I am following a Object oriented apporoach in python where i am having 2 classes and above all a defined a method as :

```
def notify_slack():

class Report(object):
  .
  .
  def new_hosts(self):
        """Return a list of new hosts added in latest scan"""
        self.curr_hosts - self.prev_hosts

  .
  .

class Scanner(object):
  .
   #Lot of code here
```

I have a main method which basically looks like :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":            
        print "New Hosts"
        report.new_hosts()     #This calls new_hosts() method in class Report
```

So, report.new_hosts() is able to call the  method defined in Report class and print the result. 
What I want to do is call `notify_slack()` and pass `report.new_hosts()` inside it, so that it prints the result to slack.

Any help appreciated, Guide me up!

Comment: *Return a list of new hosts* - that method just prints, not returns...

Comment: oh yep.. so if the method returns , then how i proceed?

Comment: You call that method and pass the result to the other method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change the `new_hosts` method to return its result instead of printing it:

```
class Report(object):
  .
  .
  def new_hosts(self):
      """Return a list of new hosts added in latest scan"""
      return self.curr_hosts - self.prev_hosts
```

You'll need to change the definition of `notify_slack` so that it takes one parameter which would be the result of calling `report.new_host`:

```
def notify_slack(host_list):
    # Don't notify Slack if list of hosts is empty
    if not host_list:
        return

    slack_msg = ' '.join(map(str, msg_list))
    slack.chat.post_message('#testbot', slack_msg,username='NMAP_bot')
```

The result of calling `report.new_hosts()` can then be passed into the `notify_slack` method.

```
notify_slack(report.new_hosts())
```

Comment: what if i want to also put a condition before sending to slack inside notify_slack(msg_list) , that the msg_list is not empty i.e if new_hosts() returns a empty list , then no notification to slack , else YES

Comment: You can check for the length of the `msg_list` and return if the length is 0 or less. I'll edit the `notify_slack` method.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is call notify_slack() and pass report.new_hosts() inside it

Like this?

```
def notify_slack(hosts):
    print hosts
    msg = ' '.join(map(str, hosts)) # delimits all the hosts by space
    slack.chat.post_message('#testbot',msg,username='NMAP_bot')


class Report(object):
    def new_hosts(self):
        """Return a list of new hosts added in latest scan"""
        return self.curr_hosts - self.prev_hosts

# s = ? 
r = s.run("172.16.0.0-255")
report = Report(r)
notify_slack(report.new_hosts())
```